# What's a word for someone who goes past their limits?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

My friend and I have been struggling to find one word for this trait!

Essentially it's someone who goes past their limits, thus experiencing intense burnout and potential consequences afterwards. They may or may not be aware of their existing limits, but they nevertheless push past them, perhaps in the heat of the moment.

As an example, take the person who is experiencing intense burnout because they partied too hard for their body to handle, so they're needing to take the next day to recharge and rejuvenate.

I know words like *rash* exist, but they seem too broad for this phenomenon.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are talking about drinking here - the expression "one over the eight" means the person is drunk. It is British military slang from the 1920s. Eight imperial pints of ale (each 25% more than a US pint) were considered a reasonable intake. One over that and you were drunk.

Comment: There is the expression "out of your league" or maybe even _"your ego's writing checks your body can't cash"_

Comment: 'Overdoer' exists but is uncommon, but "She overdoes it" is common in the UK for someone who needs to rest more. Though sometimes, it's used with a narrower focus ("I know it's right to be friendly towards the prisoners, but he overdoes it").

Comment: Are you asking for a word to describe somebody who is *currently* beyond their limits, or somebody who has a general habit of exceeding their limits but isn't necessary past the limit right now?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just said it, but it can also be applied to a person:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burnout

> **burnout**
>
> a person suffering from burnout

Answer (score 0):

As a Newfoundlander I would say that person `goes *overboard*`. Which has a few meaning variations, but can be used to reference one who has overextended themselves. Which segues nicely into `overextend` as in to overextend oneself - to go beyond your capabilities or your limits.

From there let the synonym train take you where you need to go.

> Overreach
>   Overstretch
>   Overdo
>   Etc...

Oh no, now I'm editing my response in the fear I've overextended my abilities.

Answer (score 0):

**Giving 110%**

> Giving 110% is an expression that is defined as giving all that one has plus more.
> An example of giving 110% is an employee who comes in early every day, finishes other peoples' tasks and is always the last to leave the office.
> [Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/giving-110)

Answer (score -2):

If it had a positive connotation, it would be `dedicated`. A `dedicated or committed partier` would be a `party animal`, which has a neutral connotation.

Someone inconsiderate, and incautious is `reckless`.
If you want to describe someone completely inconsiderate of boundaries in achieving a goal, I found `kamikaze`, which according to [OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/102448#eid40298588) is a

> person who acts in a reckless, hazardous, or potentially self-destructive way, esp. for a cause